# How to access Flickr API using Python?

Tags: python, flickr

I tried a few python ports of flickr api and they didn't work on my Python here which is 3.2. I also have 2.7. Do you guys know any API that is compatible with the latest Flickr API as well latest update of Python?

Comment: It might well be that none of them have been ported to Python 3. If you're willing to spend the time, you could help the community by making the best flickr package compatible with Python 3. Otherwise, you'll have to use Python 2.7 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could run Python Flickr API (http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) on Python2.7. It's not possible to run it on Python3 (according to its author).

Comment: I'm planning a version that's compatible with Python 3.2 and OAuth authentication, but it'll take a while ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Python Flickr API is now working with Python 3 - https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi-doc/ :)